# combobox change checkbox enable

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, combobox

I have an issue with my javascript. When I change combobox all of the checkbox enable. I don't want it like that. I want only each checkbox enable not all of them.
Here is my js code:

```
<script>
  function activ(){
     $("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
</script>
<script>
  function disable(){
     $("input[type='checkbox']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
</script>
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
   <body onload="disable();">
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>SELECT</th>
            <th>TAKE</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                 <select onchange="activ();">
                     <option>--Select--</option>
                     <option>Cars</option>
                     <option>Plane</option>
                     <option>Boat</option>
                 </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="check1" /></td>
         </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                 <select onchange="activ();">
                     <option>--Select--</option>
                     <option>Cars</option>
                     <option>Plane</option>
                     <option>Boat</option>
                 </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="check1" /></td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                 <select onchange="activ();">
                     <option>--Select--</option>
                     <option>Cars</option>
                     <option>Plane</option>
                     <option>Boat</option>
                 </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="check1" /></td>
        </tr>
   </body>
</html>
```

I hope any body can help me. I really appreciate for any help.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the checkbox enable corresponding to the particular select, then you have to have unique id to make the difference.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" />
```

The whole code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        select{
  width: 100px;  
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
        </style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
 $('.test').change(function(){
  var tmp =   $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type='checkbox']").attr('id');
 $('#'+tmp+'').removeAttr("disabled");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
         <tr>
            <th>SELECT</th>
            <th>TAKE</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                 <select class="test">
                     <option>--Select--</option>
                     <option>Cars</option>
                     <option>Plane</option>
                     <option>Boat</option>
                 </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="check1" /></td>
         </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                 <select class="test">
                     <option>--Select--</option>
                     <option>Cars</option>
                     <option>Plane</option>
                     <option>Boat</option>
                 </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="check2" /></td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                 <select class="test">
                     <option>--Select--</option>
                     <option>Cars</option>
                     <option>Plane</option>
                     <option>Boat</option>
                 </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="check3" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

as such.
 Check this if it satisfies what you wanted. plunker:[Enable specific checkbox](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Qv5ggdNJFq218zqCVSl?p=preview)

Now, whatever dynamic id you have for your checkbox, it will check for the change in your select, and enable only the combobox specific to it.

Comment: you have to mark it correct brother, if it satisfies your question.

Comment: I want to ask you @Alex Rumba. What if I want to get dynamic checkbox id.? Any suggest.?

Comment: Actually, it not really satifies me brother. But I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm not really satisfy because my problem not solving yet. What if I want to get dynamic checkbox id.? because all of my combobox and checkbox are from while loop.

Comment: that is quite simple,as well. Let me edit the plunker and answer. Hope, this satisfies your need.

Comment: It really satisfy me @Alex Rumba. Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: just below the voting, you will see a tick sign. You need to tick it. More like right sign, at the bottom of 0 that you are seeing. see left at the start of my answer.

Comment: Done. Thanks brother.

Comment: upvoted your question as well. Best wishes with the questions and answers.